# Problems installing a windows .exe using wine, winetricks and playitonlinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux, winetricks

The exe in question is TAV.exe, available here:  https://tav-releases.translated.com/TAV.exe It is an app that shows my availability for work. Formerly, it was based on java, and there was a workaround with java. Now it seems to be mostly dlls.
I installed wine with both prefixes (32 and 64), gecko and mono from scratch, not the versions automatically offered on install, winetricks, playonlinux and the app installed. Running it, however, the two boxes for username and password appeared, but no data could be entered, although the attempt to enter data was recorded in the terminal.
I do have the terminal output incl. screenshot of the app instances, if s.b. should be interested to help, which would be really appreciated.

Comment: Wine is a compatibility layer for some Windows applications, not all. This seems like a testing and bug report for the Wine developers.

Comment: If it doesn't show up in the application database on winehq.com, I don't think a Windows exectutable is expected to work under Wine.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answers! @user535733 Question: why do you think s.th. shows up in winehq? I would say, because s.b. tried and was lucky or very good. People, who use this app, normally work on apple or windows

Comment: @ivanovich generally it shows up because someone found out how to set it up but also after a developer added support for a specific feature. Regardless: wine questions I would ask on https://www.winehq.org/help  The experts are there not here :)

Comment: ok, thks, accepted, done. About the developer: he/she is not interested

Comment: @Rinzwind: best idea so far, really appreciate!